# htaccess conflicting with MediaWiki htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mediawiki, no-www

I have the following code in my htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^wiki/(.*)$ /index.php?title=$1 [PT,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^wiki/*$ /index.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^wiki$ /index.php [L,QSA]
```

This shorten the URL from `http://example.com/w/index.php?title=Page_title` to `example.com/wiki/Page_title`.

I would also like to redirect `example.com` to `www.example.com`, but I am not sure on how I should implement this into the existing htaccess code without conflicting with other rules.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RIght under `RewriteBase /`, add:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```